# What is the main Difference between Standard Scaler and MinMax Scaler in machine learning while preprocrssing the dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, preprocessor

I am always getting confused while preprocessing the dataset , whethere to use min max scaler or standard scaler, so basically my question is **when to use standard scaler and in which situation can I use MinMax scaler** ?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html  see this link for more information . it will help

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML methodology.

Comment: @desertnaut, Sir actually I am new in Machine learning and stack overflow as well . So I don't have much knowledge about the guidelines .

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions; non-coding questions about machine learning theory & methodology are off-topic here, and should be posted at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead. Notice the **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: In general, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MinMaxScaler` say (feature_range = (0, 1)) will transform each value in the column proportionally within the range [0,1]. Use this as the first scaler choice to transform a feature, as it will preserve the shape of the dataset (no distortion).

`StandardScaler()` will transform each value in the column to range about the mean 0 and standard deviation 1, ie, each value will be normalised by subtracting the mean and dividing by standard deviation. Use StandardScaler if you know the data distribution is normal.

If there are outliers, use `RobustScaler()`. Alternatively you could remove the outliers and use either of the above 2 scalers (choice depends on whether data is normally distributed)

Additional Note: If scaler is used before train_test_split, data leakage will happen. Do use scaler after train_test_split

Comment: Thanks for the response @Gautamrk , I got your point .